# VUE Carousel 3D Slider height

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, height

I have implemented [VUE Carousel 3D Slider](https://github.com/wlada/vue-carousel-3d) on my website but I can't find how to control the heigh on the slides. The slider has too much extra space under it due to the slides being unnecesary too high. I have tried to set heigh of a parent element:

```
#vue-slider {
    height: 100%;
}
```

but it didn't help.

Is there a setting to correctly ajust the slider height?

Here is the link where this slider is running right below the header:

https://search.rosaviabilet.ru/flights/MOW1809MIL25091

It loads with a bit of delay though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the source codes at GitHub](https://github.com/Wlada/vue-carousel-3d/blob/master/src/Carousel3d.vue#L162),

the slide height binds to the computed property=`slideHeight`, then you will see

```
slideHeight () {
    const sw = parseInt(this.width, 10) + (parseInt(this.border, 10) * 2)
    const sh = parseInt(parseInt(this.height) + (this.border * 2), 10)
    const ar = this.calculateAspectRatio(sw, sh)
    return this.slideWidth / ar
}
```

And `this.width`, `this.border`, `this.height` are the props of Carousel3d component.

Finally, you need to adjust **width**, **border**, **height** to make the slide meet your requirements.

like `<carousel-3d :height="200" :width="100" :border="1"></carousel-3d>`